# Retrieving Continuation Token in Azure DevOps Python API v7.0+ for Paginated Results

Tags: python, api, azure-devops, pagination

In earlier versions of the Azure DevOps Python API (until 6.0.0b4), when making a request on some items (e.g. WorkItems, Test Suites, ...), you had a response object with a value and a `continuation_token` that you could use to make a new request and continue parsing.

With more recent versions (in particular 7.0), you now get a list returned (but with the limit of size imposed by the API).

For example, the function of the API have changed from:

```
def get_test_suites_for_plan(self, project, plan_id, expand=None, continuation_token=None, as_tree_view=None):
    ...
    :rtype: :class:`<GetTestSuitesForPlanResponseValue>`
```

to

```
def get_test_suites_for_plan(self, project, plan_id, expand=None, continuation_token=None, as_tree_view=None):
    ...
    :rtype: :class:`<[TestSuite]> <azure.devops.v6_0.test_plan.models.[TestSuite]>`
```

I am trying to retrieve the continuation token to continue parsing the other results, but it is not being returned in the response.

Here is an example of the code I was using in older versions:

```py
resp = client.get_test_suites_for_plan(project, my_plan_id)
suites = resp.value
while resp.continuation_token:
    resp = client.get_test_suites_for_plan(project, my_plan_id)
    suites += resp.value
```

How can I retrieve the continuation token to continue parsing the other results with a more recent version (7.0 and above)?

*Note: I have already opened an issue in the GitHub repo of Azure DevOps Python API: https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/issues/461*

Answer (score 1):

I currently do an ugly patch of the `client.Client` class to add an attribute that stores a continuation token each time we send a request (with method `_send`). This is super ugly but at least it works

```py
"""Patching ADO Client to retrieve continuation token

Related to question in following issue:
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-devops-python-api/issues/461
"""
import logging
from typing import Optional, cast

from azure.devops import _models
from azure.devops.client import Client
from azure.devops.client_configuration import ClientConfiguration
from msrest import Deserializer, Serializer
from msrest.service_client import ServiceClient

logger = logging.getLogger("azure.devops.client")


# pylint: disable=super-init-not-called

class ClientPatch(Client):
    """Client.
    :param str base_url: Service URL
    :param Authentication creds: Authenticated credentials.
    """

    def __init__(self, base_url=None, creds=None):
        self.config = ClientConfiguration(base_url)
        self.config.credentials = creds
        self._client = ServiceClient(creds, config=self.config)
        _base_client_models = {
            k: v for k, v in _models.__dict__.items() if isinstance(v, type)
        }
        self._base_deserialize = Deserializer(_base_client_models)
        self._base_serialize = Serializer(_base_client_models)
        self._all_host_types_locations = {}
        self._locations = {}
        self._suppress_fedauth_redirect = True
        self._force_msa_pass_through = True
        self.normalized_url = Client._normalize_url(base_url)
        self.continuation_token_last_request: Optional[str] = None

    def _send(
        self,
        http_method,
        location_id,
        version,
        route_values=None,
        query_parameters=None,
        content=None,
        media_type="application/json",
        accept_media_type="application/json",
        additional_headers=None,
    ):
        request = self._create_request_message(
            http_method=http_method,
            location_id=location_id,
            route_values=route_values,
            query_parameters=query_parameters,
        )
        negotiated_version = self._negotiate_request_version(
            self._get_resource_location(self.normalized_url, location_id), version
        )
        negotiated_version = cast(str, negotiated_version)

        if version != negotiated_version:
            logger.info(
                "Negotiated api version from '%s' down to '%s'."
                " This means the client is newer than the server.",
                version,
                negotiated_version,
            )
        else:
            logger.debug("Api version '%s'", negotiated_version)

        # Construct headers
        headers = {
            "Content-Type": media_type + "; charset=utf-8",
            "Accept": accept_media_type + ";api-version=" + negotiated_version,
        }
        if additional_headers is not None:
            for key in additional_headers:
                headers[key] = str(additional_headers[key])
        if self.config.additional_headers is not None:
            for key in self.config.additional_headers:
                headers[key] = self.config.additional_headers[key]
        if self._suppress_fedauth_redirect:
            headers["X-TFS-FedAuthRedirect"] = "Suppress"
        if self._force_msa_pass_through:
            headers["X-VSS-ForceMsaPassThrough"] = "true"
        if (
            Client._session_header_key in Client._session_data
            and Client._session_header_key not in headers
        ):
            headers[Client._session_header_key] = Client._session_data[
                Client._session_header_key
            ]
        response = self._send_request(
            request=request, headers=headers, content=content, media_type=media_type
        )
        if Client._session_header_key in response.headers:
            Client._session_data[Client._session_header_key] = response.headers[
                Client._session_header_key
            ]

        # Patch: Workaround to be able to see the continuation token of the response
        self.continuation_token_last_request = self._get_continuation_token(response)

        return response



def patch_azure_devops_client():
    """Patch the Azure DevOps client to see the continuation token of the response"""
    # pylint: disable=protected-access
    Client.__init__ = ClientPatch.__init__  # type: ignore
    Client._send = ClientPatch._send  # type: ignore
```

Then you just need to import and call the `patch_azure_devops_client` function before creating a client and it will add a continuation_token_last_request  to the client.